# How do I check if any entry boxes are empty in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am making a GUI in Tkinter with Python 2.7. I have a frame with about 30 entry boxes among other things. I don't have access to the code right now, but is there a way to check if any or several of the boxes are empty so I can warn the user and ask them if they want to proceed?

Is there a way to go through each of them with a 'for' loop and check the length of each entry. Or is there a command to check if any box is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the content of the entry using [`Tkinter.Entry.get` method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method).

Check the length of the entry using `len` function and `get` method:

```
if len(entry_object.get()) == 0:  # empty!
    # do something
```

or more preferably:

```
if not entry_object.get(): # empty! (empty string is false value)
    # do something
```

---

Use `for` loop to check several entry widgets:

```
for entry in entry_list:
    if not entry_object.get():
        # empty!
```

You should populate `entry_list` beforehand.

Manually:

```
entry_list = []

entry = Entry(...)
...
entry_list.append(entry)

entry = Entry(...)
...
entry_list.append(entry)
```

or, using [`winfo_children`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_children-method) method (to get **all** entries):

```
entry_list = [child for child in root_widget.winfo_children()
              if isinstance(child, Entry)]
```

Comment: How would I iterate this over several entry boxes?

Comment: @user3242026, Use `for` loop: `for entry in entry_list: ...`. Of course, you should populate `entry_list` when you create entries.

Comment: how do you go about populating this list. 'entry_list.append(element)'?

Comment: @falsetru Whoops, I hadn't seen a solution was posted already when I made mine. If you add the bit about building a list from `Tk().children` I'll gladly delete :)

Comment: @adsmith, I added code that populate list of entries. BTW I used the explicitly documented `winfo_children()` instead.

Comment: @falsetru `Tk.winfo_children()` looks like it polls directly at the call, while `Tk.children` is a property that relies on the children to register themselves. Good call!